# Is it possible to tell Finale to choose automatically the best clef?

Tags: finale

Is there a way to make that Finale changes automatically the clef if a note falls a determined number of lines out of the staff?

For example, I would like Finale to set the clef of F for the last 3 beats.

[image]

This way:

[image]

I know it can be done manually with the clef tool, but I have a lot of cases of this kind that need that change to be done, so an automatical way to accomplish this task would be quite helpful...

Comment: Would you like a clef change in the top staff, the notes to end up in the lower staff, or cross-staff beaming? It's ambiguous which of these you want.

Comment: Consider asking on the Facebook group "Finale Power Users"

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the split point: it is some where beyond the plug-ins like arrangemement tools. You can choose any point like e.g. C3 or A2 etc.

You can give in the pitch or the midi number:

http://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2014Win/Content/Finale/Split_Point_Plug_in.htm

Comment: That changes staves, not clefs. I'm interpreting the question as wanting all the notes to be played by the right hand and have an automatic transition to the bass clef in the upper staff.

Comment: The example OP has given shows a grand staff, he doesn’t ask to have all notes in one stave. And if he would, he could  merge the two voices.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli thanks, what you say is helpful. However, I would like to change the clef in the same staff. I have added a picture to clarify what I was asking.

Comment: I will try to look up next time when I‘ll be on my computer ...

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Hi! Did you look up this matter?

Comment: no, not yet, yesterday I've opened finale since months again. but I will check it tomorrow. this SE thing  was absorbing me :)

Comment: have you tried this one: (I know this is not what you're looking for but it might help). https://www.finalemusic.com/blog/finale-quick-tips-one-click-mid-measure-clef-changes/

Comment: I've looked up: Sorry, I can't find a solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot anyway. Let's hope Finale allows that in future versions